# Commit hash of artefacts on Nexus when deployment is failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, commit, nexus

Let's assume that we have a maven project with following structure:

```
projectAlfa (e.g. Snapshot)
 - componentA
 - componentB
 - componentC
```

In the middle of the deployment phase (e.g. when uploading ComponentC) of artefacts to Nexus, the Jenkins job fails due to network problems.

Questions:

- Will be at all the first two components (A and B) be uploaded to nexus?
- If I request the commit hash of projectAlfa, what would I get? Will the components of projectAlfa have different states/commit hashes (e.g. artefacts of components A and B have different states/commit hashes then C)? 
  **The goal is, to get the git commit hash of snapshot artefacts. I need this information as it helps me to define, based on which git commit-hash was built uploaded snapshot artefacts on nexus.**

Comment: I guess you speak about git commit hashes? How are they related to Maven?

Comment: The goal is, to get the git commit hash of snapshot artefacts. I need this information as it helps me to define, based on which git commit-hash was built uploaded snapshot artefacts on nexus. I updated the question

Comment: Does the build in any way influence this hash? I mean, I don't understand how a failed build could influence the git commit hash.

Comment: Assume there are two commits in master branch: e.g. xxxxx1, xxxxx2. After commit xxxxx1 the project (and all compenents) will be built and deployed to nexus sucessfully But after commit xxxxx2 there is partial deployment if at all possible (see question 1). So if I get the hash commits of all artefacts which are on nexus deployed, are they the same or not which is question 2?

Comment: Partial deployment is possible. But what is the hash commit of an artifact? I only know hash commits of git repositories. I mean, if you try to build three artifacts from a git commit, and two go through and one does not, this is not nice. But how do you "see" hash commits in deployed artifacts?

Comment: This is hash commit of git. One can get git commit hash indirectly. I.e. Using Jenkins plugins/apis. Jenkins uses checked out git repository to its workspace for build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I start to understand.

If you build the project, and A and B get deployed, but C not, then the latest SNAPSHOT of A and B will belong to a different commit hash than the one of C.

The maven deploy plugin has an experimental "deployAtEnd" parameter to avoid that.

Comment: Thx for suggestion to avoid this. As the parameter an experimental, is there any other option to avoid this?

Comment: Improve your network? The case you describe seems to be really rare (at least, concerning network failure), and in this case, I would just build again.